# Convert Library React Class Component to a Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to use a library in my project that is written with React class components and looking through the documentation, I don't understand where I can get the information to know how to convert their code into a react hook.

The Library is called react-multi-carousel ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel )

and the specifics part that I can't figure out how to change is:

```
  autoPlay={this.props.deviceType !== "mobile" ? true : false}
  removeArrowOnDeviceType={["tablet", "mobile"]}
  deviceType={this.props.deviceType}
```

deviceType isn't defined, so autoPlay and removeArrowOnDevice throw an error.

So far, what I know I have to do is the following:

```
function Slider() {

    const responsive = { 

         desktop: {
          breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
          items: 3,
          slidesToSlide: 3 // optional, default to 1.

          ....etc
    }

    return (

        <Carousel>
            swipeable={false}
            .....etc 
        </Carousel>

         )
```

Thank you all in advance for your help, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Are you trying to use it inside of a functional component?

Comment: Yes exactly. What I guessed is that I had to start a function named Slider, inside copy the "responsive" const that are shown in the page, and inside that function, return the <Carousel> component. But from there on I am lost.

Comment: `<Carousel />` will only care about the values you pass. you can simply pass values to it and it will work normally [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-https-mvef7?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: No not all of them. the ones that use props and this don't (the 3 I listed on the post)

Comment: @Medi, your codesandbox also has an error and doesn't work, because it doesn't recognice ```deviceType```

Comment: @CarolinaKlein, They are just variables and since they are accessed by `this.prop`, it means you can create them as a local state for your component.

Comment: @Medi that is exactly what I don't know how to do